# pxe загрузка ubuntu с cd-rom работает, а при изменении ядра и initramfs перестает грузится

Tags: linux, pxe, initramfs

Pxe загрузка ubuntu с cd-rom работает, а при изменении ядра и initramfs перестает грузится ругается, что не хватает скриптов casper (это vmlinuz и initrd которые идут в iso установщика ubuntu). Для сборки initrd директории initramfs их нет откуда можно их взять? Нужна поддержка флешек с файловыми системами fat16 fat32, пытаюсь поставить новое ядро на pxe клиента. Ядро скопировал загружается, а initrd вываливается в kernel panic. Копирую скрипты  casper в initrd.lz собираю появляется ошибка /cow format specified aufs and support found. Ntfs флешки работают монтируются.

Comment: например, из initrd с образа установочного диска.

Comment: да оттуда скопировал собрал появились другие ошибки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да всего надо было установить пакет casper который позволяет сделать из живой системы загрузочную.

Answer (score 0):

Распакуй исошник в папку `xubuntu` в корень твоего tftp-сервака любым удобным способом.

```
/var/lib/tftpboot/xubuntu
├── boot
├── casper
├── dists
├── install
├── isolinux
├── md5sum.txt
├── pics
├── pool
├── preseed
└── README.diskdefines
```

Содержимое `/var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg/default`

```
label xubuntu-i386
    menu label ^Xubuntu 16.04 i386 LiveNet/Install [WORK]
    kernel xubuntu/casper/vmlinuz
    initrd xubuntu/casper/initrd.lz
    append boot=casper language=en locale=ru_RU.UTF-8 vga=791 root=/dev/nfs netboot=nfs nfsroot=172.16.11.8:/var/lib/tftpboot/xubuntu/
```

Кусок `/etc/exports` отвечающий за шаринг корня тфтп сервера через nfs:

```
/var/lib/tftpboot       *(ro,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

Если чё непонятно - спрашивай, дополню ответ.

Comment: нужна поддержка флешек с файловыми системами fat16 fat32

Comment: @ДмитрийВалерьевич, на каком уровне? Если прогрузить бубунту - она умеет и читать и писать на fat32.